# Which is better: adding a new object to the planning_scene_diff or publishing it on a topic?

Tags: ros, motion-planning, planning-scene, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

For adding an object to the planning scene, which is better, in which case?

(a) adding it to the planning_scene_diff (see [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Planning%20Scene/Adding%20Virtual%20Objects%20to%20the%20Planning%20Scene))

or

(b) publishing it on an arm_navigation_msgs::CollisionObject topic (see [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/motion_planning_environment/Tutorials/Adding%20known%20objects%20to%20the%20collision%20environment))

So far, I notice some facts below, please CMIIW:

(a.1) Adding objects to the planning scene does not change the current state of the world, therefore we have to always include them with our next diff in order to make them in the planning scene.

(b.1) We have to make an rviz plugin to visualize objects published in arm_navigation_msgs::CollisionObject topic.

How do you usually do for that use case?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using Fuerte, Oneiric Ocelot 64-bit)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35680/which-is-better:-adding-a-new-object-to-the-planning_scene_diff-or-publishing-it-on-a-topic?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rule of thumb I'd use is if the object really exists and you'd like to include it in a number of subsequent queries then add it to the world using the collision_object topic.  In reference to b.1., the planning_scene_validity_server should be broadcasting the latest planning_scene_information on a marker topic - the next time you start up the system try adding a marker topic and look for the one that involves "planning_scene".

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on 2012-06-06**:
Thanks Gil. Btw, pertaining to b.1., we have to call a service that gets the planning scene after publishing a new object, don't we? I think the tutorial misses (noticing) that step. Am I right?

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-10-30**:
to tor: yes. we need to call the set_planning_scene_diff service to make the collision object visible.